# Plotly add legend in hover graph

Tags: python, plotly

i am doing a graph with Plotly library and I would like to add the name of the legend inside the hovertemplate. How can I do ?

```
data = [go.Bar(name=col, 
                   x=aum_annuel_classe.index.year,
                   y=aum_annuel_classe[col],
                   xhoverformat="%Y", 
                   xperiodalignment="middle", 
                   hovertemplate = '<br>'.join([
                                               'Année: %{x}', 
                                               'AuM: %{y:,.2s}€', 
                                               '<extra></extra>'
                                               ]
                                               )
                   ) 
            for col in aum_annuel_classe.columns]
    fig = go.Figure(data)
    fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', 
                      legend=dict(yanchor="top",
                                  y=0.99,
                                  xanchor="left",
                                  x=0.01
                                  ),
                      )
    fig.update_xaxes(ticklabelmode="period",
                    tickformat="%Y"
                    )
```

[image]

Thx

Answer (score 0):

When data other than the xy axis is to be displayed in the hover data, it can be specified using the custom data function. I can't find your similar sample data, and the [sample data](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#indexing-by-geojson-properties) in plolty clearly shows the election results for a region with the number of votes for each candidate. Set each candidate as a stacked graph and set the total number of votes per region in the hover data. Specify the columns you want to add to the hover data.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go 

df = px.data.election()[:10]

data = [go.Bar(name=col,
               x=df.district_id,
               y=df[col],
               #xhoverformat="%Y",
               customdata=df.total,
               xperiodalignment="middle",
               hovertemplate = '<br>'.join([
                   'district: %{x}',
                   'Total: %{customdata}',
                   '<extra></extra>'
                                               ]
                                               )
                   ) 
            for col in df.columns[1:4]]
        
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', 
                  legend=dict(yanchor="top",
                              y=0.99,
                              xanchor="left",
                              x=0.01
                              ),
                  )
# fig.update_xaxes(ticklabelmode="period",
#                 tickformat="%Y"
#                 )
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```

[image]